# Let R* be the set of units of R and S* be the set of units of S. Prove that f(R*) = S*.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let R and S be commutative rings with unity $1_R$ and $1_S$ respectively, and let $f: R\to S$  be a ring isomorphism.

I am at a loss. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Ring homomorphisms are (defined to be) unital, this means that if $f: R \to S$ is a ring homomorphism $f(1_R)=1_S$. If you have a unit $a$ now, and consider $f(a)$, what kind of a candidate would you consider for an inverse?

Comment: @s.harp well, ring isomorphisms of rings with identity preserve identity whether or not that is among your axioms :)

Comment: @j. Medley it is a terrible idea to split your question between the title and the body of the post. Always put a complete question in the body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if $f$ is an isomorphism, let $u\in R^*, v\in S^*$. Then

> $$1_S = f(1) = f(uu^{-1})=f(u)f(u^{-1})$$

so $f(u)$ is invertible with inverse $f(u^{-1})$ and so $f(R^*)\subseteq S^*$. But then

> $$1_R=f^{-1}(1_S)=f^{-1}(vv^{-1})=f^{-1}(v)f^{-1}(v^{-1})$$

so $S^*\subseteq f(R^*)$ proving the result.